# Trying to rewrite and redirect from two parameter dynamic URL to a static URL with .htaccess,

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-redirect

I am trying to rewrite and redirect from 
http://example.com/page.php?fid=123&name=title of the blog
to
http://example.com/name/title-of-the-blog.jsp.
So that if either of the above URLs is entered in the address bar, it redirects to the second URL.

```
RewriteEngine on

#redirect from "/page.php?fid=123&name=title of the blog" to "/name/title-of-the-blog.jsp"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page\.php\?fid=([^\s]+)&name=(-[^\s]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^name/%2.jsp? [NC,L,R]
#Rewrite /name/title-of-the-blog.jsp to /page.php?fid=123&name=title of the blog
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^name/(-[^/]*)\.jsp$ /reply_forum.php?fid=$1&urdu=$2 [NC,L]
```

It does not work, it would be great if somebody could check the above code.
Thanks.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^name/-1$.jsp? [NC,L,R]` is not valid (missing pattern). But `RewriteRule ^ name/%2.jsp? [NC,L,R]` is valid (notice the space between `^` and `name`). Not sure what `-1$` is, there... Should be `%2`.

Comment: Is **name** a dynmic key?

Comment: Yes it is a dynamic key

Comment: http://example.com/page.php?fid=123&name=title%20of%20the%20blog

Comment: Starkeen meant  **key**, not **value**.

Comment: No "name" is not dynamic its value is dynamic